# LDAP Provider over OpenID (Google OAuth) backend

Tags: oauth, ldap, openid, citrix

Does LDAP Provider exist over OpenID (OpenID authentification) as back-end ?

Let me explain, I use Vdi-in-a-box from Citrix and the only authentification provider for my users is LDAP (the VDI-in-a-box default authentification system doesn't support password, just login, no security).

But all my users have Google App account, that is why I'm searching for a LDAP Provider which may use OpenID (Google OAuth) as back-end.

I found [openid-ldap](https://github.com/adrianheine/openid-ldap) but this is exactly the opposite that I want.

Comment: Hi Loic, did you get any feedback, maybe on other channels. I have the exact same situation. We use Google Apps for Business and now I want to setup an application which only supports LDAP store.

Comment: Similar question (with good answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798844/how-to-implement-an-oauth-2-0-authorization-server

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenAM by Forgrock](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14942413) which is probably what you want to do.