# How to implement an OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

I understood how to write Running OAuth 2.0 code for the client side.

Using existing Authorization Server, like Google, seems to be not too complicated.

Question is: How to implement my own Authorization Server?

Since many companies have their own User/Privilege system, LDAP based (e.g. Active Directory), etc. - they must have their own Authorization Server.

Is there a framework, libraries, etc. for that? Or do I have to write the code from scratch?

Comment: Can you add details to your question about what platform/server you might use to implement your Authorization Server? There seems to be a wide selection at [http://oauth.net/code/](http://oauth.net/code/)

Comment: Java. Preferably with Apache frameworks (like for example CXF).

Comment: Apache [oltu](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Index) looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 17):

The best reference is the [OAuth 2.0 site](http://oauth.net/2/). They list the available server libraries that you can use. Currently, the options are:

**Java**

- Apache Oltu
- Spring Security for OAuth
- Apis Authorization Server (v2-31)
- Restlet Framework (draft 30)
- Apache CXF

**PHP**

- PHP OAuth2 Server and Demo
- PHP OAuth 2.0 Auth and Resource Server and Demo
- PHP OAuth 2.0 (AS with SAML/BrowserID AuthN, with management REST API, see DEMO)

**Python**

- Python OAuth 2.0 Provider (see Tutorial)
- OAuthLib (a generic implementation of the OAuth request-signing logic) is avaliable for Django and Flask web frameworks

**Other**

- NodeJS OAuth 2.0 Provider
- Ruby OAuth2 Server (draft 18)
- .NET DotNetOpenAuth
- Erlang Oauth2 Server framework

I would also highly recommend that you read all the [documentation available](http://oauth.net/documentation/) on how the standard works before getting started. There are many parts to OAuth and it can get confusing. At least, that's how I feel.

Comment: More: Perl CatalystX::OAuth2::Provider

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenAM by Forgrock. With little work you should be able to get a java based OAuth authorization server running.

http://openam.forgerock.org/